# Solve $y’ = \frac{2-xy^3}{3x^2y^2}$ using Bernoulli form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve, by bringing the equation to Bernoulli form:

$$
y’ = \frac{2-xy^3}{3x^2y^2}
$$

---

Therefore we want to bring it to a form like:

$$
y’ + p(x)y = q(x)y^n
$$

So working with the equation i get:

$$
y’ - \frac{2}{3x^2y^2} = -\frac{xy^3}{3x^2y^2} = -\frac{y}{3x}
$$

I don’t see how to get to Bernoulli equation from here...

Answer (score 5):

You selected the wrong term. Exchange the position of terms formerly on the right side to get
$$
y'+\frac1{3x}y = \frac2{3x^2}y^{-2}.
$$

With some contemplation of the formula you could also directly detect that
$$
(xy^3)'=3xy^2y'+y^3=\frac2x.
$$

Comment: Namely you solved it also through an integration constant, how did you do that? How could you get to a linear form such from that you could extract the integration constant?

Comment: That the second approach works is an accident of the construction of the example, in trying to obfuscate the Bernoulli-structure, the original construction was left too exposed. Change the 3 into a 4, and this no longer works that nicely, still the substitution $z=y^3$ remains.

Answer (score 4):

you have $n = -2$

$$
y^\prime +\frac{1}{3x}y = \frac{2}{3x^2}y^{-2}
$$