# Solve $y’ = \frac{2-xy^3}{3x^2y^2}$ using integration factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

Show that the equation:

$$
y’ = \frac{2-xy^3}{3x^2y^2}
$$

Has an integration factor that depends on $x$ And solve it that way.

---

Already we got to:

$$
y’ + \frac{xy^3}{3x^2y^2} = \frac{2}{3x^2y^2}
$$

Therefore:

$$
y’ + \frac{1}{3x}y = \frac{2}{3x^2}y^{-2}
$$

But, in order to get an integration factor, shouldn’t we have a linear equation? Of the form:

$$
y‘ + p(x)y = g(x)
$$

That way getting the integration factor:

$$
\mu = ke^{\int p(x)}, k \in R
$$

But what we have is a non-linear equation, so how could an integration factor exists?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/differential-equations-bernoulli.html  i think this will be helpful

Comment: As you can see from [my answer to your previous question on this equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3811498/115115), you get a completely integrable equation after the multiplication with $3xy^2$. It does not get better.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that Lutz’s answer is somewhat intuition, something that i still don’t have, therefore i wanted to know if there is a more analytic way to solve this.

Comment: I have voted to close this question as a duplicate because as Aryadeva has said, to use an integrating factor, you still need the Bernoulli equation. Therefore your question is just asking the same question again.

Comment: @TobyMak I’m sure that those are not the same questions, as those are 2 questions that come one after the other in my homeworks.

Answer (score 1):

Make life easier letting
$$y=\frac z {\sqrt[3]x}\implies 3 x z'(x)=\frac{2}{z(x)^2}$$ which is simpler

Answer (score 1):

$$y’ = \frac{2-xy^3}{3x^2y^2}$$
Is linear if you substitute $w=y^3$ and $w'=3y^2y'$
$$3y^2y’ = \frac{2-xy^3}{x^2}$$
$$w' = \frac{2-xw}{x^2}$$
$$xw'+w = \dfrac 2x$$
$$(wx)'=\dfrac 2x$$
Integrate.

Comment: Thanks, but if I understand correctly what you did is exactly bernuli way to solve these equations, the point is that the previous asked to do it using bernuli and now explicitly the question asks for integration factor.

Comment: You're welcome. If you use Bernoulli you still need integrating factor @Alon And I didnt use Bernoulli's equation since I just used substittution

Comment: I did the same way. Seems the most efficient to me.

Comment: Yes I d agree with you @MathLover

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the expression and obtain $(xy^3)' = 2/x$

Answer (score 0):

$$
y’=\frac{2-xy^3}{3x^2y^2}\tag1
$$
Multiply $(1)$ by $3y^2g$ and shuffle some terms:
$$
\left(y^3\right)'g+y^3\frac{g}x=\frac{2g}{x^2}\tag2
$$
We want the integrating factor to satisfy
$$
g'=\frac{g}x\tag3
$$
So we can use $g(x)=x$. Then $(2)$ becomes
$$
\left(xy^3\right)'=\frac2x\tag4
$$
which is much easier to solve.